# Bug Check version-number on Google Playstore when coding in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Bug show in my terminal when i'm using pub dev NEW_VERSION 0.3.1

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1
E/flutter (16644): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
E/flutter (16644): #1      NewVersion._getAndroidStoreVersion (package:new_version/new_version.dart:195:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the method used in the **new_version** package is **web scrapping**. If the web playstore changes, the **new_version** package may crash and need adjustment

Hope this useful..

you can try adding **current_version** data in your **database** instead of **new_version** package or **waiting** for new update from **new_version** package

Comment: Could you edit this answer and expand on why it matters that the method is web scraping, or what that means? A code example of how to add current_version to the database could be helpful too.